# Azure VM custom script extension SAS token support

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am trying to deploy add a custom script extension to an Azure VM using an ARM template, and I want to have it download files from a storage account using a SAS token.

Here is the template (simplified):

```
{
    "name": "CustomScriptExtension"
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
    "location": "eastus",
    "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
        "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.8",
        "settings": {
            "fileUris": [
                "https://{storage-account}.blob.core.windows.net/installers/{installer}.msi?sv=2015-04-05&sig={signature}&st=2017-05-03T05:18:28Z&se=2017-05-10T05:18:28Z&srt=o&ss=b&sp=r"
            ],
            "commandToExecute": "start /wait msiexec /package {installer}.msi /quiet"
        },
    }
}
```

And deploying it results in this error:

```
{
  "name": "CustomScriptExtension",
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension",
  "typeHandlerVersion": "1.8",
  "statuses": [
    {
      "code": "ProvisioningState/failed/3",
      "level": "Error",
      "displayStatus": "Provisioning failed",
      "message": "Failed to download all specified files. Exiting. Error Message: Missing mandatory parameters for valid Shared Access Signature"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I hit the URL with the SAS token directly it pulls down the file just fine so I know the SAS token is correct. Does the custom script extension not support URLs with SAS tokens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out, this must be a bug in the custom script extension which causes it to not support storage account level SAS tokens.  If I add `&sr=b` on the the end of the SAS token (which isn't part of the storage account level SAS token spec) it starts working.

I found this info here:
https://azureoperations.wordpress.com/2016/11/21/first-blog-post/

Comment: Excellent, thanks so much for this. This solved my problem!

Comment: Hi, was this in linux vms or windows?

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful

Comment: That this workaround is still needed in 2019 Oktober is a shame. While I executed the Get-AzWebAppBackupConfiguration command on powershell everything was fine with my SAS token appended to the storage url and I could see my backup starting in the azure portal. But after 20 minutes it failed always with that error: Missing mandatory parameters for valid Shared Access Signature. YOUR solution made it working by appending it to the SAS token at the url! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: This workaround is apparently not needed anymore in 2021 March. I was able to pass file URIs with SAS tokens to the ARM template **without** adding `&sr=b` to the end and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

As @4c74356b41 said. Now, customer script extension template does not support SAS tokens. If you want to download file from a private storage account, you could use storage account key. Please refer to this [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-customscript-extension-azure-storage-on-ubuntu).

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'),'/', variables('extensionName'))]",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
        "type": "CustomScript",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
          "fileUris": "[split(parameters('fileUris'), ' ')]",
          "commandToExecute": "[parameters('commandToExecute')]"
        },
        "protectedSettings": {
          "storageAccountName": "[parameters('customScriptStorageAccountName')]",
          "storageAccountKey": "[parameters('customScriptStorageAccountKey')]"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Look at my example script again, I am putting the SAS token into the URL, so if you know the full URL (because you have the SAS token) it is a public URL, and that would be like saying public URLs are not supported.  I figured it out, see my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is support for SAS token in VM Extension

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not support SAS tokens. Refer to this feedback item:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-linux-extensions/issues/105