# Terraform - custom_data not running when creating virtual machine

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-machine, winrm

I'm trying to configure WinRM during the creation of a Windows virtual machine using Terraform.

My os_profile and os_profile_windows_config is:

```
os_profile {
    computer_name  = "server-name"
    admin_username = "${var.vm_username}"
    admin_password = "${var.vm_password}"
    custom_data = <<EOF
    <powershell>
    winrm quickconfig -q
    winrm set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="300"}'
    winrm set winrm/config '@{MaxTimeoutms="1800000"}'
    winrm set winrm/config/service '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
    winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{Basic="true"}'

    netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WinRM 5985" protocol=TCP dir=in localport=5985 action=allow
    netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WinRM 5986" protocol=TCP dir=in localport=5986 action=allow

    net stop winrm
    sc.exe config winrm start=auto
    net start winrm
    </powershell>
    EOF
  }  



os_profile_windows_config {
    provision_vm_agent = true
    winrm {
       protocol="http"
     }
  }
```

When I rdp to the VM I can see a `CustomData.bin` file in `C:\AzureData` but it hasn't executed any of the Powershell. Am I right in thinking that this should have been executed or is there another step I need to take to execute this?

Answer (score 0):

No, it should not. its just a base64 (as far as I remember its base64 encoded, might be wrong) encoded string dumped to a file. you need to decode\execute it using other means

Comment: Any idea what to use or how to execute? I'm having major problems trying to get a script onto a VM and then execute it.

Comment: use powershell dsc or script extension. script extension is fairly straight forward

Comment: I've tried custom script extension but it requires my script to be in a public container or publicly available on git. I can't do this due to the nature of the script. There is no way to use custom script extension and pass in account credentials like there is when using an ARM template.

Comment: you can use sas tokens with the script to securely download it from the azure storage
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43752262/azure-vm-custom-script-extension-sas-token-support

Comment: Just been looking into this and can't see where I can pass a sas token into the azurerm_virtual_machine_extension resource

Comment: check accepted answer, it shows how to do that, anyway, this is not part of the original question, i suggest you accept this answer and start a new one if you cant figure this out

Comment: How can I accept as an answer when my question hasn't been answered? I've checked the accepted answer on the other post and my sas token already has `&sr=b` at the end so it doesn't help.

Comment: you question was answered, this is a new one

Comment: It really wasn't. It's pretty clear what i'm asking for and any answer you have supplied doesn't work. Hence why i'm still unable to get the Powershell above to run when creating a new VM.

Comment: your question was why custom data is not running, i've answered that, now you ask another question and i've answered that and you ask one more... really?

Comment: It's pretty obvious what i'm trying to achieve here. Any help was appreciated but the accepted answer in the post you linked to wasn't helpful. This does not mean my query was answered.

Answer (score -1):

To execute your script on a Windows machine, you need to execute a custom script extension using the `azurerm_virtual_machine_extension` resource. Here you can refer to the `CustomData.bin` file and execute it.

Please check this [link](http://teknews.cloud/bootstrapping-azure-vms-with-terraform/), it explains in nice detail how to bootstrap both Linux and Windows VMs

Comment: I'm really interested in that link as I'm looking into how to bootstrap a linux VM. The link is dead. Don't link. Explain in the answer.